# How to have the docker container logs on the host machine

Tags: docker, containers

Where the docker container console logs are stored. And how can I have the console logs of docker container stored on my host?

I tried below to get the log location. This pointed me to file at `/var/lib/docker/containers/` But I dont find any directory called as **docker** at /var/lib inside the docker container

```
docker inspect --format='{{.LogPath}}' <container id>
```

I want to collect the logs which we get from `docker logs <containerid>` to have/mount it to my host.

Comment: That’s a path on the host system, not inside the container.  Usually things in `/var/lib/docker` are considered implementation details and you shouldn’t be directly using them.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
docker ps
```

to find CONTAINER ID

and

```
docker inspect <CONTAINER ID>| grep LogPath
```

to find logs, but a better approach is to use directly:

```
docker logs <CONTAINER ID>
```

Comment: As mentioned in my post, I tried docker inspect, and it pointed me to /var/lib/docker/containers/ location, but when i go inside the container, I don't see the directory at all.

Comment: Ya I know, I can see the logs by docker logs <containerid>, but I want all the console logs to be available on my host machine. So, if I would get to know the location of log file, I can do the volume mount.

Comment: 1. pls cd to `LogPath` from host machine,  2. to collect all docker logs from docker host machine to should follow: https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/logging/configure/ - it is possible to push all logs to syslog or es for instance.

Answer (score 0):

```
   docker logs <CONTAINER_NAME> or <CONTAINER_ID>
```

like:

```
   docker logs container1
```

The container should be started and running. 
Very useful to see what happens behind the container execution in context and methods and ...

hope it helped.